# Why does the array count up in the "button" type, but not in the "modal-body" class in Handlebars?

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I am creating a dynamic website, I work with arrays a lot, the problem is that the nested div does not iterate through the items of the array and always take the values of the first item. The iteration works properly in the same div as the for-each is placed. Does anyone have an idea how fix this problem?

Thx

```
<div class="dropdown show">
{{#each items}}

<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
  {{Fruit}}
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">{{Fruit}}</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
   

        Type = {{type}}
        <p></p>
        {{juice.value}}
        <p></p>
        {{color.value}}

      </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>

<p></p>

{{/each}}

</div>
```